# Please help me to return a list from my method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get information from a database, convert it to a list and return the CustomerList.  This first bit of code works fine.  The second example is where I’m trying to accomplish the same thing except the fields are coming from my database.  What’s wrong with what I’m doing and how can I make this work? The second piece of code works elsewhere in my project but not here.

```
private SchoolIn.Models.CustomerList CreateCustomerList()
{
    return new SchoolIn.Models.CustomerList()
    {
        new SchoolIn.Models.Customer { Id = 1, Name      = "Patrick", Address = "Geuzenstraat 29", Place = "Amsterdam" },
        new SchoolIn.Models.Customer{ Id = 2, Name = "Fred", Address = "Flink 9a", Place = "Rotterdam" },
        new SchoolIn.Models.Customer { Id = 3, Name = "Sjonnie", Address = "Paternatenplaats 44", Place = "Enkhuizen" },
        new SchoolIn.Models.Customer { Id = 4, Name = "Henk", Address = "Wakerdijk 74", Place = "Utrecht" },
        new SchoolIn.Models.Customer { Id = 5, Name = "Klaas", Address = "Paternatenplaats 44", Place = "Plaantan" }
    };
}

private SchoolIn.Models.CustomerList CreateCustomerList()
{
    return new SchoolIn.Models.CustomerList()
    {
        SchoolInDB db = new SchoolIn.Models.SchoolInDB();
        var courseprogresses = db.CourseProgresses.Include(c => c.Course).Include(c => c.Teacher);
        return View(courseprogresses.ToList());
    };
}
```

Comment: Leuk dat mijn stadje op SO staat! #enkhuizen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first the second code is invalid C#. So I suppose it doesn't event compile. You cannot use such expressions in an object initialization syntax. Please learn C# before getting into ASP.NET MVC.

The other problem is that your method is private and you are attempting to return View which is something that you do in a controller action. The view method returns an ActionResult whereas your method return type is SchoolIn.Models.CustomerList which once again is wrong.

So move this into some controller action where you would instantiate your database access context and then perform the query and return the model to the corresponding view for display:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    ...

    public ActionResult CreateCustomerList()
    {
        SchoolInDB db = new SchoolIn.Models.SchoolInDB();
        var courseprogresses = db
            .CourseProgresses
            .Include(c => c.Course)
            .Include(c => c.Teacher)
            .ToList();
        return View(courseprogresses);
    }
}
```

and if you wanted to keep this into a separate method:

```
private List<SchoolIn.Models.CourseProgress> CreateCustomerList()
{
    SchoolInDB db = new SchoolIn.Models.SchoolInDB();
    return db
        .CourseProgresses
        .Include(c => c.Course)
        .Include(c => c.Teacher)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: The code seem to work but I now get an error message:   private List<SchoolIn.Models.CustomerList> CreateCustomerList()
        {
            SchoolInDB db = new SchoolInDB();
         
            {


                return db
                    .CourseProgresses 
                    .Include (c=>c.Course)
                    .Include(c=>c.Teacher )
                    .ToList ();


            }

Comment: @CloudyKooper, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you should consider marking it as answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 1):

In your first function you are returning actual list while in second function you are not returning list, instead you have returned the View with model as a list. So for it you need to return View Result viz. ActionResult.

Hope it helps

Comment: Now get a conversion error message. Here’s the error message:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SchoolIn.Models.CourseProgress>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SchoolIn.Models.CustomerList>' 

Here’s the code that works except for the ToList().

private List<SchoolIn.Models.CustomerList> CreateCustomerList()
        {
            SchoolInDB db = new SchoolInDB();
         
    
                return db
                    .CourseProgresses 
                    .Include (c=>c.Course)
                    .Include(c=>c.Teacher )
                    .ToList();
}

Comment: check your return type, it is List of Course Progress Type and return type of your method id list of CustomerList Type this both should be same..